# Combine excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export-to-excel

Can someone help how to get output in excel readable format? I am getting output as dataframe but #data is embedded a string in row number 2 and 3

```
import pandas as pd
import os
input_path = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Test/'

output_path = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Test/'
[enter image description here][1]
excel_file_list = os.listdir(input_path)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in excel_file_list:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df1 = pd.read_excel(input_path+file, sheet_name=None)
        df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)enter image description here
        
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('combined.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for sheet_name in df.keys():
    df[sheet_name].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you add sample output that you get and the output you expect?

Comment: Would you clarify what is the readable format that you are expecting?

Comment: @GeekGroot  I am looking to read output in excel format having data in each sheet. I am not able to add screen shot of input and output file. My input and output file are excel file with multiple sheets. It is just output file as combined data from all workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be in using `sheet_name=None`. If any of the files have multiple sheets, a dictionary will be returned by pd.read_excel() with {'sheet_name':dataframe} format.

To .append() with this, you can try something like this, using python's Dictionary.items() method:

```py
def combotime(dfinput):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    for k, v in dfinput.items():
        df1 = df1.append(dfin[k])
    return df1
```

EDIT:  **If you mean to keep the sheets separate** as implied by your `writer` loop, do not use a pd.DataFrame() object like your `df` to add the dictionary items. Instead, add to an existing dictionary:

```py
sheets = {}
sheets = sheets.update(df1) #df1 is your read_excel dictionary
for sheet in sheets.keys():
    sheets[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=Fasle)
```

Comment: I get df1 as combined data in one sheet but i want data to have in each sheet and just keep on appending new workbook data into same sheet within folder. I tried your suggestion but sheets has null values do i am getting error of AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'. Can you advise how to get data in same sheet as input file and data get appended from other workbook with same sheet name.

Comment: Let say one workbook with sheets name xyz and pqr and other workbook with same sheet name. Output file have one workbook with same two sheet names. In my folder there are more then two workbooks and each workbook have multiple sheets with same names or different name.